# C# audio device enumeration and muting

Tags: c#, windows-7, directsound, xaudio2

Since `DirectSound` is deprecated and `XAudio2` removed enumeration, what is the "right" method for a C# application to enumerate and modify audio devices on Windows 7 and above?

I've seen solutions that use [NAudio](https://naudio.codeplex.com/), [CSCore](https://cscore.codeplex.com/), or other libraries and wrappers.  Are there bare-metal solutions for C#?